# Windows 11 high CPU usage on window resizing

Tags: gpu, cpu-usage, task-manager, windows-11

I opened Task Manager. When I put the mouse in its window's border and resize the window rapidly, make it bigger then make it smaller and doing this continuously for a few seconds, strangely CPU usage goes higher than 20 percent. if I stop resizing, CPU usage come back to normal.
I have a Thinkbook 14 Gen2 itl with 16G Ram and corei7-1165g7 as cpu and MX450 as GPU
Why this simple task is CPU hungry?
see my screenshot:
[image: high cpu usage occurs when resizing window]

**Edit1** : 
I repeated this action in a windows 7 system and CPU usage remained 0% ! so I think something is wrong with windows 11.

Comment: The resize is not CPU hungry - repainting the window is.

Comment: @harrymc but I think this simple task should not use 10 percent of cpu, Is this occurs in your laptop too?

Comment: You resize a window and that is done. What is continuing to go wrong with Windows 11?  (2 ThinkPad X1 Windows 11 Pro and NO issue).

Comment: @John I want to test my laptop cpu power! Is resizing a window too hard for a 11th gen cpu? it sounds crazy, I expect more than this from a 300$ cpu!